# Keras CNN model throws a memory issue when I try to train it

Tags: numpy, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN and I am trying to make a basic cat vs dog CNN model using Keras on this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data), which consists of 12500 images for cats and dogs each i.e. a total of 25000 images.
My current approach to process data is as follows:

Convert all images to size 128x128 --> Convert them to numpy array --> Convert all of them to b/w image --> Divide them by 255 for normalization --> Use data augmentation --> Train CNN using them

(It was giving a memory issue if we use color images)

Here is my model I am trying to train:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu', input_shape = (128,128, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
          
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
          

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (2,2),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (2,2),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
          
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))
          
          
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer = optimizer , loss = "binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
          
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', patience=3, verbose=1, factor=0.5, min_lr=0.00001)
```

But, whenever I try to start training i.e. `call model.fit_generator`, it prints Epoch(1/30), then throws this error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[86,128,64,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node conv2d_4/convolution}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[metrics/accuracy/Identity/_117]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  (1) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[86,128,64,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node conv2d_4/convolution}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

and training stops.

I know it having some issues related to my pc memory, as I am trying to train it on my local Windows system.
My question is, what should I do to solve this.

I cannot degrade quality of images any further, I am aready using b/w image for less memory consumption.

My system's memory:
8GB RAM,
2GB Nvidia GeForce 940MX graphics card

Here is my complete python notebook [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VWmWQ34aENAL1X7ctzu5lmvhJp04_RV2/view?usp=sharing) if anyone needs complete code.

also, it throws following warning when I execute `from keras.models import Sequential`

```
FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
```

Comment: 2 GB is not much, reduce 512 to 128 or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the entire dataset into your main memory. This is not advisable if you big dataset as you will almost always run out of memory.

A solution to this is using TensorFlow's `flow_from_directory` method which allows you to load the batches whenever they are required instead of keeping your entire dataset in memory.
**Code:**

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

Your code will look something like this.

With this you can do image augmentation as well load the data without storing it in main memory.

See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#expandable-1) for image augmentation options.

See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) for flow_from_directory options.

Here, the labels are inferred from the directory names.
Your directory structure should look something like this.

```
train
    - cat
        - img1
        - imgn
    - dog
        - img1
        - imgn
```

[This](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cyufpmPappTx5CR44ly80lCzvOHvh2w4?usp=sharing) is a link for a complete end to end example using the above method.

**Note:** Your `steps_per_epoch = total_samples / batch_size`

If you still get an OOM error.

1. Try reducing batch size
2. Try reducing image size
3. Try reducing image channels ie (RGB --> Grayscale)
4. Try reducing model size.

Comment: Yes, thanks for this information, it should work for me

and sorry, I can't upvote it currently as I have less than 15 reputation

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the answer. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.